# Is it safe to have common grounds in this circuit?

Tags: ground

[image]

For the sake of simplicity, I draw the illustration above.
System A is a device which is fed by a power supply 110V AC, and has sinusoid output with varying amplitude from 1V to 7V peak to peak.

Sytem B will be comparator which will convert these sinusoids to pulses and it is fed by another 12V power supply.

My questions are the following:

Is it safe to make all grounds common?

Do I need a shunt resistor between the device output and the comprator? IF so, what should be the value of it? 100k is ok?

edit: GND of 110V AC is isolated from GND of DEVICE output.

Comment: It would be WRONG to feed an AC supply using hot and ground.

Comment: @Andyaka I checked and edited question. GND of 110V AC is isolated from GND of DEVICE output. Is it safe now?

Comment: You should use hot (live) and neutral (return). Calling it "ground" means I regard it as "earth" and this means that a whole protection system based on ground current interruption cannot be used. Thus it is unsafe regardless of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be more than one "ground" here.  The ground that goes with the 110 VAC line voltage may be isolated from the DC voltage produced by the power supply internal to the left device.  Therefore GND at its bottom and GND at its right may not be connected.  However, that doesn't matter.

Not only is it OK to connect GND (the green wire) between the device and the comparator, it is essential.  Voltages are relative between two conductors.  The SIG line by itself doesn't contain any information without something as a reference.  GND is the obvious reference.

Presumably the comparator device has a single ground, so its red GND and green GND are connected internally.

Comment: so it is safe? just to be sure.. what about do I really need the shunt resistor?

Comment: @user16307: We have no way of knowing whether you need it or not. You have supplied no details of the device or comparitor.